# Multi-armed UCB parameter: what is $B$?

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

UCB uses a padding function such as $$c_t(i)=B\sqrt{\xi \log(t) / N_t(i)},$$
where $B$ is an upper-bound on the reward.

This description comes from reference 2 (also see reference 3). But I have seen it described it as such elsewhere.

I see many people using $B=1$.

My question is, what is $B$ exactly? An upper-bound on the reward distribution? But too often, the reward distribution does not have an upper bound, it follows a Gaussian say. I am new to the literature, so I must be missing something...

References:

1. The original paper: [Sample Mean Based Index Policies with O(log n) Regret for the Multi-Armed Bandit](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1427934), by Rajeev Agrawal
2. [On Upper-Confidence Bound Policies for Non-Stationary Bandit Problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3415) (see page 3), by Aurélien Garivier and Eric Moulines
3. [A Survey of Online Experiment Design with the Stochastic Multi-Armed Bandit](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.00757.pdf), by Giuseppe Burtini, Jason Loeppky, Ramon Lawrence

Comment: I believe it's an upper bound on the *expected* reward, so if you have $k$ arms and a collection of reward distributions over time $\mu_t(k)$, $B = \max\mu_t(k)$.  Could be wrong, though.

Comment: Based on the discussion in the paper just before the Algorithm 1 block, I think it's an upper bound on the random variables. A lot of the early bandit work focused on variables in [0,1], which is consistent with the OP saying he sees "B=1" often.

Answer (score 1):

The term "UCB" stands for "Upper confidence bound", because the algorithm optimistically selects arms which *might* be very good. The term $B\sqrt{\xi}$ controls what precisely this means. From your reference 2 (page 3):

> $B$ is an upper bound on your rewards and $\xi$ is an appropriate constant

We don't need to limit the analysis to finite rewards - in fact your reference 1 considers Gaussian and Poisson models (see section 5).  Typically the constants fall out of the regret analysis and are chosen to minimize the expected regret. [Sebastian Bubeck gives a very good review](http://sbubeck.com/SurveyBCB12.pdf)  on UCB algorithms which describes this in the context of subgaussian rewards.